# Tagging Suggested For Split Exchanges

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way / is it possible to give a tooltip or something of the sort that if a post is tagged with a certain keyword, the tooltip can say that that there is a specific exchange for this tag.

For example, [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), and soon [Joomla](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla) has their own specific exchanges. So if a user enters one of those tags a tool tip would appear letting them know there is a specific exchange dedicated to this tag.

1. This would push more questions / more traffic to newer popular exchanges
2. Let new users know there is more than just the 1 stack exchange
3. Decrease the number of unanswered questions to specific CMS tags

Currently for each of the 3 tags listed here's how unanswered questions stand:

1. [WordPress - 21,490](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15)
2. [Drupal - 4,080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal)
3. [Joomla - 3,896](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla)

Comment: This _might_ minimize the number of migration requests to move these to other sites.  I'd however be concerned that these sites would start to get questions that are badly worded or asked. Currently, we don't migrate crap and I'd hate to have crap go to these sites just because a tooltip tells them about the site.

Comment: On the WordPress exchange the moderators are usually pretty good at closing poor questions quickly and leaving constructive comments, which since the exchange isn't flooded with thousands of questions daily it's relatively easy compared to stackoverflow which gets questions of any and every language / framework. I would consider it splitting the responsibilities.

Comment: @bluefeet Wordpress and Drupal are graduated sites. They should be able to handle the extra traffic. Protecting public beta sites from excess traffic is a reasonable argument, but I don't think we should extend the same to graduated sites, otherwise what's the point behind graduating at all?

Comment: If only people actually read tag excerpts, then we could simply put the recommended site there...

Comment: There's also [arduino], [raspberry-pi], [wolfram-mathematica], [sharepoint] (16,071 questions!), [salesforce], [robotics], [graphic-design], [tor], [tridion], and [user-experience]